# Sumar ingresos y gastos de un data frame en R

Tags: r, r-dplyr, dplyr, summarise

tengo unos datos bancarios como los siguientes:

```
Año     Importe
2011     35   
2011     25  
2011    -10 
2011    -23  
2012     45
2012     55   
2012     65  
2012    -20 
2012    -23  
2012    -35
etc...
```

y me gustaría sumar los valores de Importe agrupados por año, pero los valores positivos por un lado y los negativos por otro lado para finalmente tener un dataframe con ingresos y gastos por año. Algo como esto:

```
Año     Ingresos     Gastos
2011     60            33
2012     165           78
etc...
```

Le he estado dando vueltas, he agrupado con dplyr por años pero a la hora de sumar no consigo hacerlo. ¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Son dos problemas: la agrupación por año y la suma condicional, la forma más básica en R es:

```
aggregate(Importe ~ Año, 
          datos, 
          FUN=function(x) {
           cbind(sum(ifelse(x>0, x, 0)),
                 sum(ifelse(x<0, x, 0)))
            })
```

Resultado:

```
   Año Importe.1 Importe.2
1 2011        60       -33
2 2012       165       -78
```

Agrupamos con `aggregate()` con la formula `Importe ~ Año`, es decir, agrupamos por año y la agregación se hace por `Importe`, luego simplemente es especificar una función de agregación que sume de forma condicional en dos columnas `cbind(sum(ifelse(x>0, x, 0)), sum(ifelse(x<0, x, 0)))`